# Why doesn't Application_Error in my global.asax catch the “500:Internal server error”?

Tags: asp.net, exception, global-asax

When a response is returned with StatusCode (500), the Application_Error sub in my Global.asax is not being fired.

Comment: Certain types of internal server error may result in the server not being able to run *any* of your code. How would you propose for this to work in such a circumstance?

Comment: The error is happening in IIS before asp.net is invoked. Your web server is boned.  Check the logs.